# How do I auto BCC all e-mails from Outlook 2013?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2013

There are lots of questions on how to auto BCC e-mails from specific senders or with specific subjects, but I had a ton of trouble finding a simple rule to just auto BCC everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code, courtesy of [GroovyPost.com](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/how-to-automatically-bcc-in-outlook-2010/):

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
                             Cancel As Boolean)

Dim objRecip As Recipient
Dim strMsg As String
Dim res As Integer
Dim strBcc As String
On Error Resume Next

' #### USER OPTIONS ####
' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address or resolvable
' to a name in the address book
strBcc = "SomeEmailAddress@domain.com"

Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
objRecip.Type = olBCC
If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
    strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
      "Do you want still to send the message?"
    res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
      "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
    If res = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If

Set objRecip = Nothing

End Sub
```

NB: The script runs after you hit "send," so you won't see anything in the BCC field while you're writing the e-mail.